# session folder exceed size of 4096

Tags: php, session, nginx

On my ubuntu production server session folder exceed size of 4096 and contain lot of files. As result nginx very often is down and show gateway error 502

I using ngixn server nad php fpm. Also I checked crons and cron for deleted expired session files exist

```
drwx-wx-wt  4 www-data www-data       4096 Feb 27 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 64 root     root           4096 Feb 26 19:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data       4096 Apr 13  2015 modules
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data 1060098048 Feb 27 11:25 session
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: delete any file older than 2 days. Does the script to delete expired sessions not run correctly or at all?

Comment: Seems like script does not run correctly.